# S3 Java API Acknowledgement

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am writing a java program to add/delete/modify files in an S3 bucket.If I use

```
client.deleteObject(bucketName, key)
```

the key if it exists gets deleted and if that key is invalid, nothing happens.

Is there any way to get acknowledgement of `deleteObject()` and `putObject()` so that one can know that an add or delete option has successfully been done? This is definitely required in `deleteObject()` where I want to confirm if the given key exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the AWS SDK is pretty good documented. That is you should probably consult the JavaDoc first.

Regarding your question, the methods `AmazonS3.putObject(PutObjectRequest)` and `AmazonS3.deleteObjects(DeleteObjectsRequest)` return a `PutObjectResult` or a `DeleteObjectsResult`. These objects contain the wanted information...

Comment: "The method deleteObjects(DeleteObjectsRequest) in the type AmazonS3 is not applicable for the arguments (DeleteObjectRequest) "

Comment: Its `DeleteObjectsRequest` and not `DeleteObjectRequest`. I fixed my typo

Comment: "DeleteObjectsResult.getDeletedObjects().size()" returned 1 even if the key doesn't exist in the given bucket and hence I cannot figure out if that object was (present and deleted) or not. I guess if there is any method which checks if a key exists in a bucket, that might serve my use case.

Comment: @user3528600 The `DELETE` action is idempotent.  After attempting to delete an object, the object definitely is not there, therefore the request succeeds. If there is no error, success means "object deleted, if present."  Think of `DELETE` as enqueueing a request to ensure that the object is absent.  That's not really technically precise but conceptually, it's valid.